Installing Bluetooth software
I dug my Amazon Echo device out of my trash to see if I can get it to work as intended. I believe I tried everything that the Amazon website said in order to diagnose the issue. During the process, at one point the Echo device said "I can not communicate". I discovered that I do not have Bluetooth capability on my Echo.
I bought a Linux approved Bluetooth dongle. The software CD had no
ASUS USB-BT400 USB Adapter w/ Bluetooth Dongle Receiver, Laptop & PC Support, Windows 10 Plug and Play /8/7/XP, Printers, Phones, Headsets, Speakers, Keyboards, Controllers,Black : ElectronicsLinux software.

I have run sudo apt install blueman bluez* so far.
This is the rest of my question that I have not done yet. Before I go any further, can I continue with these instructions?
Starting the Bluetooth Daemon:
To have Bluetooth available each time you boot your computer, we need to enable and start bluetooth.service, the daemon that Bluetooth connectivity. We do this with systemctl.
Enabling the service means it'll be started with each boot of your computer. Starting the service makes it run right away, so you can use Bluetooth without having to reboot your computer.
Enabling the bluetooth.service :
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service

Starting the bluetooth.service :
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service

Checking the status:
We can check that Bluetooth is up and running using the rfkill command. This scary-sounding command lets us check the health and status of wireless communications, and Bluetooth falls into that category.
Using rfkill without any command-line parameters lists the wireless adapters, and shows whether they are blocked or unblocked
rfkill

We can see that Bluetooth is present, but blocked. We can sort that out using rfkill with its unblock option. Of course, you might find that your adapter is unblocked, in which case you don't need to perform the next step.
Unblocking the Bluetooth adapter:
rfkill unblock bluetooth

Now we can check the status with rfkill once more.
It says it trying to connect but can not. ??
~$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
[sudo] password for andy: 
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
~$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
~$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# 


I have not found the answer.

@karel   bluetoothctl says it trying to connect but can not. ??

The output of bluetoothctl suggests that the issue may not be with your Bluetooth setup in Ubuntu but could be related to the Amazon Echo device itself (if it's defective or it's not in pairing mode).

You can continue with the instructions for given in your question for enabling and starting bluetooth.service, the daemon that manages Bluetooth functionality including searching for Bluetooth devices and establishing a connection by handling pairing requests.
The output of bluetoothctl at the end of your question suggests that the issue may not be with your Bluetooth setup in Ubuntu, but could be related to the Amazon Echo device itself (if it's defective or it's not in pairing mode). The following steps will help you to connect your Amazon Echo and troubleshoot the problem further if necessary.
The message "I cannot communicate" from your Amazon Echo suggests that the device is having trouble establishing a connection to the network or pairing with another device like a computer or phone via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi. The results of sudo dmesg | grep -i blue from a previous revision of your question showed that the Bluetooth system on your Ubuntu 24.04 is active and functional, and the necessary Bluetooth core services are successfully initialized. What remains to be done is to connect the Amazon Echo.

Check the Ubuntu Bluetooth settings with bluetoothctl to see if the Amazon Echo is listed as a paired device. Run the following commands in an interactive shell.
power on  
agent on  
default-agent  
scan on # Start scanning for nearby Bluetooth devices

Then try unpairing and re-pairing the device.
Unpairing:
power on
scan on
paired-devices # Check if Echo is paired
remove <device-MAC-address> # MAC address of your Echo from paired-devices

Pairing:
pair <device-MAC-address>
trust <device-MAC-address>
connect <device-MAC-address>
exit # then test the connection if the Echo responds correctly to a voice command


Make sure your Echo device is connected to Wi-Fi by checking the Alexa app or the Echo's settings.

Even if the Echo is connected to Bluetooth or Wi-Fi, it still needs to access Amazon's servers for most of its functionality. Make sure your Echo is connected to the correct network and there are no issues with the router or network password.

Make sure that the Echo's speakers and microphone are working correctly and that the device is not muted.

If  the first four steps didn't work try resetting the Echo back to its factory settings and setting it up again.



bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# How do I try unpairing and re-pairing the device.
